# how to compile java progem using another jar

Tags: java

I want to compile java programs using  another jar.
actually other jar contains method , which i am using in my java program..

I tried the -cp command , but after running a java program it require actual jar i.e used for compilation .

Comment: Please check this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091733/how-do-i-compile-a-java-file-that-has-jar-dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091733/how-do-i-compile-a-java-file-that-has-jar-dependencies)

Comment: *"I tried the -cp command , but after running a java program it require actual jar i.e used for compilation"*. Correct, that's how Java works. It sounds like you're looking to make a [fat jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150811/what-is-a-fat-jar).

Comment: yes i want to make single jar of 3 java program that will work anywhere without other jars(the jar which is used for compilation of java files) .   is it possible using CMD ? if yes then could u please help in that....