# run java file in linux command with maven dependencies

Tags: java, linux, shell, maven, centos

I have written a Java program with `intellij` and it's working, but now I want to run this file with a command, but when I try to compile it with javac I get errors because it doesn't recognise my imports, I'm new to programming so how can I run my program knowing that it has dependencies in maven?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please share your error

Answer (score 1):

If you have a choice, you should use maven command (mvn) rather than the low-level compiler javac, it makes compiling and packaging much easier.

But if you want to use javac, you must pass the path to the jar your code depends on, as explained in : [How do I compile a java file that has jar dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091733/how-do-i-compile-a-java-file-that-has-jar-dependencies?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

If you have pulled your dependencies using maven and you are using centos, the jars should be stored in directory ~/.m2

But once again you should consider installing and using maven, if you want to manually compile your code in a similar way Intellij does

Answer (score 0):

Maven was created to make it easier to handle builds with dependencies (jar files) which can be automatically downloaded from the internet.  This includes invoking `javac` with all the dependencies on the build classpath using "mvn compile" - you do not have to invoke javac yourself!   Look in target/classes for your byte code files compiled by Maven.

You can also ask Maven to run your Java class with the required dependencies available.  Use the following command (adapted as necessary):

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main"
```

See http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html for more details.