# package javax.servlet does not exist although the package is found by vsCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, servlets

When importing the javax.servlet package in the java file, this package is found by vsCode. However, when I compiled the file I get the error 'package javax.servlet does not exist'. I don't know how to solve this problem. I cleared workspace, but it doesn't work. Tomcat5.5,vsCode1.67.2,java1.5,jdk1.5

[image]

Comment: When you compiled the file how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the source files reference third-party library (`JAR`) files, use the `-cp` option and specify the `JAR` file. For example:

```
javac -cp lib\mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar -d classes src\TestDb.java
```

If there are multiple `JAR` files, they must be separated by semicolon like this:

```
javac -cp lib\mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar;lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar -d classes src\TestDb.java
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply compile the source file via `javac xxx.java` since you have a dependency in your code.

Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9091749/13068918

Comment: 感谢大哥！！！！！！！！！！！！