# JUnit .class through cmd

Tags: java, class, junit, cmd

I have a Junit Test file for a java program, how do I generate the Junit .class file through the cmd?

What steps do I need to take and what is the command for this?

Below is the Test File.

```
package java_testcases.junit.crt_program;


public class BITCOUNT_TEST {
    @org.junit.Test(timeout = 3000)
    public void test_0() throws java.lang.Exception {
        int result = correct_java_programs.BITCOUNT.bitcount((int)127);
        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals( (int) 7, result);
    }

    @org.junit.Test(timeout = 3000)
    public void test_1() throws java.lang.Exception {
        int result = correct_java_programs.BITCOUNT.bitcount((int)128);
        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals( (int) 1, result);
    }

    @org.junit.Test(timeout = 3000)
    public void test_2() throws java.lang.Exception {
        int result = correct_java_programs.BITCOUNT.bitcount((int)3005);
        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals( (int) 9, result);
    }

    @org.junit.Test(timeout = 3000)
    public void test_8() throws java.lang.Exception {
        int result = correct_java_programs.BITCOUNT.bitcount((int)256);
        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals( (int) 1, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using any tool for building your project, like maven or gradle? If no, then you will need to provide all jars like 'javac -cp ".;/libs/junit.jar;/project_jar.jar" BITCOUNT_TEST.java'. More can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091733/how-do-i-compile-a-java-file-that-has-jar-dependencies

Comment: no I'm not. what do you mean by all jars? Do I need to download something extra?

Comment: Yes. If you are using any IDE, then it also needs external jars to compile and run your code. But it hides it from you. When You need to run the code, you need to provide those jars in some way. That is why people use tools like gradle/maven to handle those dependencies. And execute all tests, etc