# Java work on intelliJ but don't work in console terminal

Tags: java

I tried to run my code on terminal, but when i try to do that appear an error like that:

```
javac .\Server.java.\Server.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(socket);
                ^
  symbol:   class ClientHandler
  location: class Server
.\Server.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(socket);
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class ClientHandler
  location: class Server
2 errors
```

I tried with java, javac, java -jar, java -cp, java -classpath command too.
All not work!

Comment: Show the actual commands you ran, including all the arguments.

Comment: I'd recommend using Maven/Gradle to package and run your code, rather than `javac` manual compilation and running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `ClientHandler` is not an standard library class, it's either written by you class, either a class from some library. In the first case please don't forget to include all source directories to javac command line as `-sourcepath` (more information for example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/javac-compile-classes-directory)). In the second case don't forget to include dependency library as classpath via `-cp` (more information for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091733/how-do-i-compile-a-java-file-that-has-jar-dependencies))